# Why 2 cameras with separate focal lengths should be used to make an FPS animation?

Tags: animation, camera, workflow, unity

Is there a reason that I should use 2 cameras, one for the main character and one for the environment, when making an FPS animation?

I was going to start making my 1st FPS animation and was looking for guides to get me started and came across [this CG Cookie post](https://cgcookie.com/articles/how-great-first-person-animations-are-made-10-tips-for-animating-fps-characters-in-blender). Tip 6 mentions using 2 cameras with different focal lengths.

It says it's to prevent the animation from feeling weird if I decide to change the focal length but I don't quite understand it. Is it just so I can get multiple points of view of the animation, or does having the camera affect the animation or change something when I put it in Unity?

Comment: As far as I understand, you are supposed to set up one camera for your player's view which you don't ever change.
If you need different views, eg. for cutscenes, you should use a different camera so your perfectly fine-tuned settings for the player cam don't get lost. Switching cameras is preferable to changing camera settings.

Comment: From CGcookie video, it alredy shows what would look like when changing feild of view with single cemar. https://youtu.be/dclA9iwZB_s?t=213